# Как сделать единый генератор slug

Tags: laravel, slug

Столкнулся с проблемой, что на некоторых версиях `laravel` генерация slug происходит по разному

**laravel 5.7**

```
$test = 'Лист алюминиевый';
echo Str::slug(mb_substr($test, 0, 200), '-');
//list-alyuminievyy
```

**laravel 7.0**

```
$test = 'Лист алюминиевый';
echo Str::slug(mb_substr($test, 0, 200), '-');
//list-alyuminievyj
```

**laravel 8.12**

```
$test = 'Лист алюминиевый';
echo Str::slug(mb_substr($test, 0, 200), '-');
//list-alyuminievyi
```

Как я понял, за это отвечает `laravel/helpers`. Обновить на старых версиях нет возможностей из-за зависимостей пакета

Есть универсальное решение для генерации урл?

И какой вариант урл верный?

Comment: Можно свой метод создать - везде и всегда будет одинаково

Comment: Таки да, я бы тоже сделал свой метод. А какой вариант считать верным — это ваш личный выбор